# Running PowerShell scripts without using Sitecore PowerShell Extensions module

Tags: powershell-extensions, powershell

We are facing some issues with Lucene during installation of PowerShell Extensions module (SPE).

**Is there any option to run Sitecore scripts from Windows PowerShell?**

I mean that I will just add some route to PowerShell instance or make some config changes and it can be used similarly as web based PS extension?

Running `Sitecore 8.2 Update 5` and tried to install `SPE 4.7 for Sitecore 8`.

Thanks for any advises.

Comment: Can you post also another question with issues that you have with Lucene during installation of SPE? Best would be to fix root cause and not to spent time on some workarounds. But definitely this is good question needless to say :)

Comment: Yeah, i will post some log files, but nevertheless it would be much more comfortable if i could run scripts remotely and not using extensions :/

Comment: I have tried to install SPE 4.7 and also 4.7.2 on clean instance of Sitecore 8 but no issues during installation. Seems that you have some trouble with custom configuration

Answer (score 4):

There is an option of performing the minimal installation, which does not make use of Sitecore items.

You can find more details on the [security page](https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/security.html) in the book.

The Sitecore Marketplace has the minimal installation package, which is a standard zip file of configs and dlls that are dropped into your Sitecore bin/App_Config directories.

Answer (score 3):

In answer to your other question, you can run commands from a powershell console using SPE's remoting feature: https://sitecorepowershell.gitbooks.io/sitecore-powershell-extensions/remoting.html

Answer (score 0):

I managed how to fix this issue.
It is not the best solution, but it may help someone.I found errors when post installation events were triggered. So from:

```
Sitecore.ContentSearch.config
```

I removed all event nodes containing:

```
packageinstall:items:ended
```

This fixed the problem.

Then I was able to install PSE locally. Nevertheless I found out, that this was not about PSE only, it was actually happening among all packages installation.

As I said it may not  be the best way, but since we do not care about content search at all, this seemed to be the easiest solution.

Hope It can help someone.