# Creating new items using powershell from csv

Tags: powershell

I want to know is there any way to create new items in sitecore using the powershell with data from excel sheet

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Should be fairly simple. You can use the PowerShell `Import-CSV` command to load a CSV file in:

```
$importRows = Import-CSV "C:\path-to-your-file\import-data.csv"
```

Then you can enumerate through that and create the items using the `New-Item` command. This example assumes a field name in the CSV of `ItemName`. For speed you probably want to wrap this in a `BulkUpdateContext`

```
New-UsingBlock (New-Object Sitecore.Data.BulkUpdateContext)
{
    foreach ($row in $importRows)
    {
        $itemName = $row.ItemName
        $newItem = New-Item -Path "master:\content\parent-item" -Name $itemName -ItemType <Set the template path & name>
        # Now you can edit the $newItem and set some field values too
    }
}
```

That should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps.

1. Go to admin site by accessing this link "myproducts/sitecore" site using proper credentials
2. Create a template e.g. products with columns you mentioned -Product Name -Product Title - Product Description
   [image]
3. Now configure powershell in your sitecore instance if not done already. See below link.

https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Sitecore_PowerShell_console.aspx

[Running PowerShell scripts without using Sitecore PowerShell Extensions module](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/11031/running-powershell-scripts-without-using-sitecore-powershell-extensions-module)

4. Once installed properly Go to powershell from sitecore admin site
5. Follow instruction given above by Richard.

   $row in Richard's solution above will give you access to entire row at a time.
6. Create items based on templates you created under designated path of your content tree

Answer (score 0):

Find the `PowerShell Code` below:

```
#Define path you want to create sitecore Items
$parentPath ="master:/sitecore/content/Helixbase/Models"
#Read CSV file
$importList = Import-CSV "C:\CSVFile\SampleCSVImport.csv"
foreach ( $row in $importList ) {
    $name = $row.Title
    #Check if Title is not empty
    if($name.Trim() -eq "")
    {
        write-host "Item name should not be blank: " $name  
        continue
    }
    $itemPath = $parentPath + "/" + $name #Create Item path
    $currentItem = Get-Item -Path $itemPath -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue #Get the sitecore Item
    if($currentItem -eq $null) #Check if Item is null then create new Item
    {
        try
        {
            $item = New-Item -Path $itemPath -ItemType "/sitecore/templates/Project/Helixbase/Page Types/Sample Page"                                
            write-host "Item created: " $itemPath             
        }             
        catch
        {
            write-host "Failed to create Item: " $itemPath                
            write-host $_.Exception.Message    
            continue
        }
    }
    #Assign Field values to the Sitecore Item  
    $item.Editing.BeginEdit()
    $item["Title"] = $row.Title
    $item["Description"] = $row.Description
    $item["Summary"] = $row.Summary
    $item.Editing.EndEdit()
}
```

for more details refer to Blog Post: [Import CSV Data in Sitecore Using PowerShell](https://himmatsinghdulawat.blogspot.com/2021/05/import-csv-data-in-sitecore-using.html)